# Legacy refactoring from procedural to OOP

Tags: php, oop, refactoring, workflow

I have inherited a site that is written in PHP, using an entirely procedural way of doing things.  Currently, it is not easy to extend and I am wanting to refactor the entire codebase.  However, I'm not really sure about how to go about this.  I've never had to refactor something like this before and don't want to completely break it.  Are there any resources that you could point me toward before I began this endeavor?

I'm mainly confused about workflow.

Comment: This is exactly why I wrote [Modernizing Legacy Applications in PHP](https://leanpub.com/mlaphp). I've been in your situation several times over the past 15 years, so I put all my notes together into a series of step-by-step instructions that will help you convert your page-based include-oriented spaghetti mess into a codebase that is autoloaded, dependency injected, unit tested, layer separated, and front controlled. There are some free chapters online and a recording of one of my talks about it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any common workflow for this, but you have to think about :

- Which framework to use (unless you've never used a framework AND you have no time no learn AND your current site is very simple OR you do this for pedagogical reasons : **do NOT build your own OOP structure**)
- No to break anything : have a test site, and test everything. Anyway, you MUST break everything at some point - but nobody must see it.
- Potentially use paper, pen and schemes